# AngularJS: ng-repeat from second index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to ng-repeat but only from the second array element until the last. I tried to use

```
ng-repeat="entry in entries | filter: $index==0"
```

but this one didn't work. If I attempt to use `ng-if`, like this

```
ng-repeat="entry in entries" ng-if="$index != 0"
```

I am getting error in transclusion.

What's the best solution for this? BTW, my AngularJS version is 1.1.5 because my app is a plugin for Hawtio (which is still stuck in version 1.1.5). Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why not just:

```
ng-repeat="entry in entries.slice(1,entries.length)"
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/10d6o1aq/

Comment: I'll use the first element somewhere else in the html, so this may not be an option.

Comment: @menorah84 don't be afraid , it is only the sliced copy of an original array in a view

Comment: Ok, thanks, I used your solution, however not in the html part (for some weird reason it does not do what it's supposed to do in html) but in javascript, I just used another variable that references 2nd element until last using slice method.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
ng-repeat="entry in entries" ng-show="!$first"
```

Here's the [reference](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat).

Comment: Yes, as Mukund mentioned later, `ng-hide="$first"` is also valid.

Answer (score 5):

hide first element using `$first`

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in entries" ng-hide="$first">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a simpler solution in more recent versions of Angular (which won't work for the original question, given their restriction on Angular version 1.1.5, but it will work for others coming across this post)

The filter "limitTo" now supports a "begin" argument ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)):

```
{{ limitTo_expression | limitTo : limit : begin}}
```

So you can use it like this in a ng-repeat:

```
ng-repeat="entry in entries | limitTo: entries.length : 1"
```

This means that ng-repeat will begin at index 1 (instead of the default index 0) and will continue for the rest of the entries array's length (which is less than entries.length, but limitTo will handle that just fine).