# Skip first item in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want to skip the first item in ng-repeat

```
..first item here  

<ul class="highlight-topright">
        <li ng-repeat="item in hpHeadlines | filter:$index>0">
          ...
        </li>
</ul>
```

it doesn't work, anything wrong here ?

I understand that i can use ng-if, ng-show to hide things but I just cannot get why the filter doesn't work in 1.3.x in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: `$index` is variable set by `ng-repeat` on the scope. You can not reference it from the filter which is evaluated before the directive starts doing anything. Also I don't think this syntax is supported by the filter component. However you can use function based expression which takes `index` as its second argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: ng-repeat from second index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624341/angularjs-ng-repeat-from-second-index)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
<ul class="highlight-topright">
        <li ng-repeat="item in hpHeadlines" ng-if="$index > 0">
          ...
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Another alternative is `ng-if="!$first"`.

Answer (score 33):

**Use $first for this**:

```
<ul class="highlight-topright">
        <li ng-repeat="item in hpHeadlines" ng-hide="$first">
          ...
        </li>
</ul>
```

Or,

```
  <ul class="highlight-topright">
            <li ng-repeat="item in hpHeadlines" ng-if="!$first">
              ...
            </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 14):

You can also use the [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter.

> As a negative index, begin indicates an offset from the end of input. Defaults to 0.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in hpHeadlines | limitTo: 1 - hpHeadlines.length">
  ...
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am late to answer this. But just for newbies, I am providing solution. As you want to skip the first record, so you can use either $index or $first for achieving, as shown below:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in hpHeadlines" ng-if="$index">       OR

<li ng-repeat="item in hpHeadlines" ng-if="!($first)">
```

As you could see, in both, ng-if is skipping '0' value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-show` or `ng-if` without using it as a filter. It's easier because you know the index you want to skip.

Use filters usually when you want to do something that concerns all the array, such as formatting for instance, or parts that you don't know where they reside.

```
<ul class="highlight-topright">
        <li ng-repeat="item in hpHeadlines" ng-show="$index != 0">
          {{item.name}}
        </li>
     </ul>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9482/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-show instead, like this:

```
<ul class="highlight-topright">
    <li ng-repeat="item in hpHeadlines" ng-show="$index > 0">
      ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or you can use **ng-if** directive in case you don't want to add invisible dom elements.