# Create a table with rowspan using a template on an angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, templates, html-table, directive

I have created a custom directive to out put a fairly simple tabular data. This is my current code:

```
app.directive('searchResult', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { content: '=' },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var html = '<table class="table table-bordered">';
            angular.forEach(scope.rows, function (row, index) {
            if (row.names.length > 1) { 
               var names = row.names;
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td rowspan='+row.names.length+'>'+row.num +'</td>';
                html += '<td>'+names[0] + '</td>';
                html += '</tr>'

                for (var i = 1; i < names.length; i++) {
                   html += '<tr>';
                   html += '<td>'+names[i] +'</td>';
                   html += '</tr>';
                }
           } else {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>'+row.num +'</td>';
                html += '<td>'+row.names[0] + '</td>';
                html += '</tr>';
        }
        })
        html += '</table>';
        element.replaceWith(html)
        }
    }
});
```

The problem with this code is the binding. If a user searches a new item, the directive will create a new table above the previously displayed result instead of replacing the old result.

I am trying to use templateUrl and have a template that has {{content}} inside and the binding works. The old search result is replaced by the new one.

Is there a way to perform this table code creation inside a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $compile service after you are done with your html.

[$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Instead of:

```
element.replaceWith(html)
```

Try:

```
html = $compile(html);
```

It should keep all Angular.js binding. However it is not a good practice, as you are forcing an extra scope refresh.

Comment: Thanks! May I know what the best practice would be?

Comment: Create external template, use ng-repeat. Don`t concate strings inside your javascript. Don`t use forEach use for loop and your brain. https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/37

Comment: Got it. I didn't know you can do that with just ng-repeat. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the my case using templates by using this code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>            
        <tr ng-repeat-start='myEntry in content'>
            <td rowspan="{{myEntry.names.length}}">{{myEntry.num}}</td>
            <td>{{myEntry.names[0]}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat='name in myEntry.names' ng-if="$index > 0">
            <td>{{name}}{{myEntry.names}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Some of the codes are based from the links found in SO:

- [Here's the link for creating tables with rowspan using ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104750/angularjs-use-of-rowspan-to-group-hierarchical-data)
- [This link is for skipping first item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645279/skip-first-item-in-ng-repeat)

Thanks it Michał Lach for pointing out of a more elegant way of doing this.