# How to make a div sortable after first row in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I used ng-repeat to create the div based layout for records, now i want that first row should not be effected while sorting.

Say

```
Name Age Area
V    29    C
S    20    D
D    39    F
V    28    P
```

If user click on Name (Sorting should happen both ways asc and desc)
but after first row.

Result Should be like

```
Name Age Area
V    29  C
D    39  F
S    20  D
V    28  P
```

I am using angular $filter('orderBy') to do sorting

Code Used:

```
<div class="heading row titleBar">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 m-name tog" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('user.name', reverse);" data-predicate='name'><h4 class="name on" data-ng-bind="name"></h4></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 t-name tog" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('user.title', reverse);" data-predicate='title'><h4 data-ng-bind="title"></h4></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 s-name tog" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('user.userStatus', reverse);" data-predicate='userStatus'><h4 data-ng-bind="status"></h4></div>
</div>

<div class="profiler complete-profile animation_1" ng-class="{active:show}" id='{{$index}}' ng-repeat="memberList in recordField = (List.slice(0,pageSize))">

                    <div class="table-row clearfix">
                    /*code*/

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Js

```
$scope.order = function(predicate, reverse) {
        $scope.List = $filter('orderBy')($scope.List, predicate, reverse);
    };
```

Is there any configuration that can be set to achieve it.

Comment: remove first element when using ng-repeat and display first element as it as before ng-repeat

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skip first item in ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645279/skip-first-item-in-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to slice the first item from the array, and then concatenate the rest of the filtered sliced array.

```
$scope.order = function(predicate, reverse) {
  $scope.List = $scope.List.slice(0, 1)
    .concat($filter('orderBy')($scope.List.slice(1), predicate, reverse));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

just use "ng-if" in the div tag. $index gives the current index inside the ng-repeat

```
<div class="profiler complete-profile animation_1" ng-class="{active:show}" id='{{$index}}' ng-repeat="memberList in recordField = (List.slice(0,pageSize))" ng-if="$index > 0">
```

Comment: If we use $index>0 first result will not going to be present on DOM itself.

Comment: display the first element in a different div above that